# whats the difference between C strings and C++ strings?

Tags: c++, c, string

whats the difference between C Strings and C++ strings. Specially while doing dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Do you mean the difference between using `char*` and `char[]` strings in the two languages, or the difference between `char` based strings and `std::string`?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "C string" and "C++ string".  Both (especially the latter) are ambiguous.

Comment: Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ and http://www.macdonald.egate.net/CompSci/hstrings.html

Comment: I can't come up with something they might have in common.  I'll have to sleep on that.

Comment: C does not really have Strings, They are just char[] which by convention are terminated by \0. There are many C++ String Libraries.

Comment: C++ string are not NUL terminated, while C strings are.

Comment: @Gollum, that's probably an implementation issue. I don't think there's anything in the standard to say that C++ strings aren't _allowed_ to be null-terminated. In fact, it may make `c_str` easier to implement.

Comment: I think generally they are nul terminated, to save on creating a temporary buffer when calling c_str()

Answer (score 45):

I hardly know where to begin :-)

In C, strings are just `char` arrays which, by convention, end with a NUL byte. In terms of dynamic memory management, you can simply `malloc` the space for them (including the extra byte). Memory management when modifying strings is *your* responsibility:

```
char *s = strdup ("Hello");
char *s2 = malloc (strlen (s) + 6);
strcpy (s2, s);
strcat (s2, ", Pax");
free (s);
s = s2;
```

In C++, strings (`std::string`) are objects with all the associated automated memory management and control which makes them a lot safer and easier to use, especially for the novice. For dynamic allocation, use something like:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
s += ", Pax";
```

I know which *I'd* prefer to use, the latter. You can (if you need one) always construct a C string out of a `std::string` by using the `c_str()` method.

Answer (score 17):

C++ strings are much safer,easier,and they support different string manipulation functions like append,find,copy,concatenation etc.

one interesting difference between c string and c++ string is illustrated through following example

```
#include <iostream>                            
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[6]; //c string
    a[5]='y';
    a[3]='o';
    a[2]='b';
    cout<<a; 
    return 0;
}
```

output **»¿boRy¤£f·Pi»¿**

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
  string a; //c++ string
  a.resize(6);
  a[5]='y';
  a[3]='o';
  a[2]='b';
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

output **boy**

I hope you got the point!!

Comment: This kind of behaviour from C is what causes bugs like Heartbleed.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is speed in some operations, and encapsulation of places where common errors occur.
std::string maintains information about the content and length of the string. This means it is not prone to buffer overruns in the same way a const char * is. It will also be faster for most operations than a const char * because the length of the string is known.
Most of the cstring operations call strlen() under the hood to find out the length of the string before operating on it, this will kill performance.
std::string is compatible with STL algorithms and other containers.

Lastly, std::string doesn't have the same "gotcha!" moments a char * will have:

Comment: C strings are not `char *` or `const char *`; they are just null-terminated character arrays. Even string literals are just character arrays.