# why a pointer char cause a segmentation fault in a struct environment

Tags: c, string, pointers

I"m a begginer in C, usually I used C++. I try to work whith a `struct` with a `char` array in it, but when I used an other `char *str` it raises a `segfault`.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_obj t_obj;

struct s_obj {
    char *str;
};

int main() {

    char *str; // if disable no segmentation fault
    t_obj obj; 
    printf("%lu\n",strlen(obj.str));
    return(0);
}
```

---

I tried to understand what you mean by "the argument of `strlen` must be a string" @anastaciu... so I tried to make a code to do that, but the result is the same: `segfault` when an other `char *str` is used.

I can't find a way to init my `char *str` in the struct.

```
typedef struct s_obj t_obj;
struct s_obj {
    char *str;
};

int main() {
    char *str; // if disable no segmentation fault fault
    t_obj obj;
    obj.str = strcpy(obj.str, "truc");
    // printf("%lu\n",strlen(obj.str));
    printf("%s\n",obj.str);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: _"... a struct with char array in it"_ - no it doesn't. An array would be something like `char str[100]`. What you have is a _pointer_ which you never initialize and which does not point to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
printf("%lu\n", strlen(obj.str));
```

Invokes undefined behavior, the argument of `strlen` must be a string, aka a null terminated char array, `obj.str` is not a string it is just an uninitialized pointer, you'll need to allocate memory for it or othewise make it point to a valid memory location.

For example:

```
t_obj obj;
obj.str = calloc(100, sizeof *obj.str); //99 character string, 0 initialized 
                                        //malloc does not "clear" the allocated memory
                                        //if you use it you can't use strlen before strcpy
printf("%zu\n",strlen(obj.str)); //will print 0, the string is empty
obj.str = strcpy(obj.str, "truc");
printf("%zu\n",strlen(obj.str)); //will print 4, the length of the string
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1yWG06oNNBoKPw9m)</kbd>

Tha fact that the program does not behave as badly when you remove  `char *str;` is a matter that's well within the scope of [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3):

Comment: @Knupel there was a typo in my answer, in line 2, I corrected it and added an online example, note that in your answer you don't allocate enough memory for your array, you should correct that.

Answer (score 1):

C is not C++ ;) Seems you've missed an important difference regarding the two.

C++ Example:

```
#include <string>
struct t_obj {
    std::string str;
};
void foo(){
    t_obj obj; // <-- In C++ this is enough to get a properly initialized instance.
}
```

In C++, this code will give you a properly initialized object with an (also initialized) string.

But in C (as in your sample):

```
typedef  struct t_obj  t_obj;
struct t_obj {
    char *str;
};
void foo(){
    t_obj obj; // <-- Nothing gets initialized here.
}
```

There is no initialization as in the C++ example above. `obj` will simply be a chunk of (not initialized) memory. You have to initialize it yourself.

There's also a Problem with your 2nd sample:

`strcpy` does not work that way. We need to pass an allocated chunk of memory to `strcpy` and it will copy data to that place we gave to it.

But as we pass a "not initialzed pointer", strcpy will try to write our data *somewhere* in memory.

I think question "[whats the difference between C strings and C++ strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454948/4415884)" might be helpful. It explains some details about the difference of C and C++ strings.

Answer (score 0):

In either case, you are using `obj.str` uninitialised.

The address it holds in indeterminate, and the content of the memory location it points to also indeterminate. So, it's not null-terminated, and using it with `strlen()` (i.e., with the functions which expects a string argument), will cause out of bound access, which is essentially invalid memory access, which in turn invokes undefined behaviour.

For reference, `C11`, chapter 7.24, String handling `<string.h>`

> *[...]Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values,[...]*

At least, initialize the pointers to a null-value.

Answer (score -1):

now the code work fine like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_obj t_obj;
struct s_obj {
    char *str;
};

int main() {
    char *str;
    t_obj obj;
    if (!(obj.str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
    obj.str = strcpy(obj.str, "truc");
    printf("%s\n",obj.str);
    free(obj.str);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You allocate exactly one char, and then _happen_ to get away with a buffer overrun. It's a bug. Just use `strdup` if you can't figure out what size to allocate.