# Why do strings still work sometimes even when you don't include the string library in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm learning to code using C++. I learned that to use the `string` datatype you need to include the `<string>` library, but how does this code still work when I haven't included the `<string>` library?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs a `string` to the console without me needing to include the `<string>` library. Shouldn't it return an error?

Comment: C-strings are part of the language. are you talking about std::string?

Comment: I don't understand how I have the ability to use a string when I haven't imported the string library. Is the string library only needed when you create string variables?

Comment: `"Hello World!\n"` is a string literal. It is not a `std::string` object, it is a `const char[14]` array, which decays to `const char*`. There is a standard `operator<<` for `const char*` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between a `std::string` object (that comes from the `<string>` header file) and a C-style string. You do not need to include the `<string>` header file in order to use C-style strings, as they are built-in to the language. This is mainly due to the fact that a C-style string is just an array of characters, ie an array of bytes, and is found within the instruction set architecture. `std::string` objects are more commonly used than C-style strings in C++, due to the methods involved, and their ease of operation. See the following helpful links:

[whats the difference between C strings and C++ strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454900/)

[std::string vs C-strings](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/07/26/stdstring-vs-c-strings/)

Answer (score 2):

The text `"Hello World!\n"` is not a `string` but an array of chars: `char[14]`, which allows you to print to the console without any additional includes.

Comment: "*`<iostream>` eventually includes `<string>`*" - that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. As I said in my answer: `(depending on your compiler)...but you cannot rely on this...`

Comment: The problem with your last statement is that you are encouraging the reader to rely on `<string>` being included in `<iostream>`, and treating the *actual* truth (that the standard requires or gives assurance of no such thing) as the exceptional or unexpected case.

Comment: @Peter I've removed the contentious statement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've removed the contentious statement.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely being included with iostream

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the compiler.
`<iostream>` *includes* `<string>`

But as I said before it's not necessary.
It depends on the compiler.